# Flowfiles are getting stuck in the nifi processor

Tags: apache-nifi, cloudera

This is the query I am using to introduce a delay of 30 minutes in the processor :
`${now():toNumber():gt(${flowfile-in:multiply(1000):plus(1800000)})}`

But sometimes its happening that the `flowfiles` are getting released in 1hr or 1hr30mins
What might be the possible reason for this?
For looping for those 30 mins I tried an execute wait processor but this issue still persists.

Comment: Where you are using this expression? What's in "flowfile-in" ?

Comment: @daggett its a now:tonumber attribute that we are adding at the time of ingestion

Comment: Where you are using this expression?

Comment: @daggett its being used inside a RouteonAttribute processor.

Comment: Also, what I observed is these are getting stuck in only one of the our clusters.